# Android Java Jni c++ Memory leaks

Tags: android, c++, ffmpeg

I'm facing problems with my code. It has a pretty high memory consumption and with time can hit 1GB RAM.
I'm using c++ and ffmpeg lib to read audio samples and generate waveforms but I really can't find where the leak is.

Here is my code:

```cpp
extern "C"
JNIEXPORT jint JNICALL
Java_modules_Waveform_decode_1to_1pcm(JNIEnv *env, jobject thiz, jstring input, jstring output) {
    const char * filename = (*env).GetStringUTFChars(input, 0);
    const char * outfilename = (*env).GetStringUTFChars(output, 0);
        if((*env).PushLocalFrame(1) != JNI_OK) {
            __android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_ERROR, "exception: ", "%s", "Failed to open capacity");
            return -1;
        }
        /* Open File */
        AVFormatContext * format_ctx{nullptr};
        int result_open = avformat_open_input(&format_ctx, filename, nullptr, nullptr);

        result_open = avformat_find_stream_info(format_ctx, nullptr);

        int index = av_find_best_stream(format_ctx, AVMEDIA_TYPE_AUDIO, -1, -1, nullptr, 0);

        /* Finding decoder */
        AVStream *streams = format_ctx->streams[index];
        const AVCodec *decoder = avcodec_find_decoder(streams->codecpar->codec_id);

        AVCodecContext *codec_ctx{avcodec_alloc_context3(decoder)};

        avcodec_parameters_to_context(codec_ctx, streams->codecpar);

        /* Opening decoder */
        result_open = avcodec_open2(codec_ctx, decoder, nullptr);

        /* Decoding the audio */
        AVPacket *packet = av_packet_alloc();
        AVFrame *frame = av_frame_alloc();

        SwrContext *resampler{swr_alloc_set_opts(
                nullptr,
                streams->codecpar->channel_layout,
                AV_SAMPLE_FMT_FLT,
                streams->codecpar->sample_rate,
                streams->codecpar->channel_layout,
                (AVSampleFormat) streams->codecpar->format,
                streams->codecpar->format,
                streams->codecpar->sample_rate,
                0
        )};

        std::ofstream out(outfilename, std::ios::binary);
        while (av_read_frame(format_ctx, packet) == 0) {
            if(packet->stream_index != streams->index) {
                continue;
            }

            result_open = avcodec_send_packet(codec_ctx, packet);
            if(result_open < 0) {
                // AVERROR(EAGAIN) --> Send the packet again getting frames out!
                if(result_open != AVERROR(EAGAIN)) {
                    __android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_ERROR, "exception: ", "%s", "Error decoding...");
                }
            }
            while (avcodec_receive_frame(codec_ctx, frame) == 0) {
                /* Resample the frame */
                AVFrame *resampler_frame = av_frame_alloc();
                resampler_frame->sample_rate = 100;
                resampler_frame->channel_layout = frame->channel_layout;
                resampler_frame->channels = frame->channels;
                resampler_frame->format = AV_SAMPLE_FMT_S16;

                result_open = swr_convert_frame(resampler, resampler_frame, frame);
                if(result_open >= 0) {
                    int16_t *samples = (int16_t *) frame->data[0];
                    for(int c = 0; c < resampler_frame->channels; c ++) {
                        float sum = 0;
                        for(int i = 0; i < resampler_frame->nb_samples; i ++) {
                            if(samples[i * resampler_frame->channels + c] < 0) {
                                sum += (float) samples[i * resampler_frame->channels + c] * (-1);
                            } else {
                                sum += (float) samples[i * resampler_frame->channels + c];
                            }
                            int average_point = (int) ((sum * 2) / (float) resampler_frame->nb_samples);
                            if(average_point > 0) {
                                out << average_point << "\n";
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
                av_frame_unref(frame);
                av_frame_free(&resampler_frame);
            }
        }
        av_frame_free(&frame);
        av_packet_unref(packet);
        av_packet_free(&packet);
        out.close();
        (*env).PopLocalFrame(nullptr);
        (*env).ReleaseStringUTFChars(input, filename);
        (*env).ReleaseStringUTFChars(output, outfilename);
    return 1;
}
```

I tried ticks like (*env).ReleaseStringUTFChars and (*env).PopLocalFrame(nullptr) but it's not working. The memory consumption is still very high

Comment: Well, without being familiar with ffmpeg, just by looking at the code a few obviously wrong things stand out. There's a call to something called `avformat_open_input` that looks like it allocates something. I find nothing, whatsoever, in the shown code that obviously deallocates whatever `avformat_open_input` allocates. This sticks out like a sore thumb. A simple search, using a highly advanced search engine that everyone heard of, finds a page that, in addition to `avformat_open_input`, also lists something called `avformat_close_input`.

Comment: Thanks @SamVarshavchik That's was a mistake of mine and yes avformat_close_input reduced greatly part of the leak but I still feel there are more. I think I have to study more the code!

Comment: Yes, I'm sure there's more. I would pull out all the C++ code, remove all JNI dependencies, and run the whole thing under `valgrind`.

Comment: Ahhh bro!
With avformat_flush(format_ctx);
        avcodec_flush_buffers(codec_ctx);
        avcodec_close(codec_ctx);
        avformat_close_input(&format_ctx);
The leaks are completely gone XD
Thank you very much buddy

Comment: Unrelated: your `PushLocalFrame`/`PopLocalFrame` pair does nothing productive.

Comment: I should agree @Botje